# Upper bound for a probability expression

Tags: probability

There are $M=\{1,\dots,m\}$ machines and $N=\{1,\dots,n\}$ are a set of $n$ numbers. Suppose $m<n$. On the $t^{th}$ trial, each machine $m$ picks a number from $N$ with probability $p_m(t,,n)$. If more than one machine picks the same number, those machines experience a collision.

All machines start off with independent uniform distributions at time $t=0$. A machines keeps the first number it got without a collision for the rest of the time with probability one. Those who still didn't have any trial without a collision, pick a number again with independent uniform distributions. (i.e. hold the number with the fist no collision event)

To make it clear: those who hold their number (after fist successful trial) still do collide with others, but they don't change the number since they had at least one no collision incident in the past for that number, others have to retrial. This goes on till everyone is collision free.

What is the probability that there is at least one collision at time $t>0$?I am not sure if this probability can be found easily in closed form, but can we find an upper bound? And using that upper bound can we say that the sum probability (sum over time) of at least one collision goes to zero?

**Edit:**

Trying to prove: Suppose the event that at least one collision occurs at time $t$ is $C(t)$ with probability $P(C(t))$. Then I'm trying to say $\sum_tP(C(t))<∞$. Hoping to apply Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: My attempt resulted in finding out that at time $t=0$ the probability of collision is the Birthday problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem. There is an upper bound for that. But it becomes complicated after that.

Comment: Is the solution going to be evaluated by a computer or do the expressions have to be without summations and/or recursion? I'm writing an answer now that will work, but is not easy to compute by hand (I think).

Comment: @Ragnar I want know if the sum probability of collisions (summed over time) to go to zero. So that I can claim by using Borel-Cantelli lemma that the collision will stop after some time. So to that end any expression is fine I think. Thank you.

Comment: So you don't need an exact probability of machines with a fixed number in a certain time?

Comment: That is right, I don't need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works for $m <\infty$. Fix an arbitrary time and suppose $k<m$ machines have already settled (meaning they have already picked their choice in previous rounds). The probability that in the next round, a fixed unsettled machine becomes settled is:
$$\frac{n-k}{n}\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m-k-1} \ge \frac{n-k}{n}\cdot \left(1-\frac{m-k-1}{n}\right)\ge \frac {m-k}{m}\cdot\left(1-\frac{m-1}{n}\right)\ge \frac{1}{m^2}$$
Let $U(t)$ denote the number of unsettled machines at the end of round $t$. Then by the above argument, in expectation, $\frac{1}{m^2}\cdot U(t)$ become settled in the next round. Repeating the argument, we get:
$$E[U(t)] \le E[U(0)]\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)^t = m \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)^t$$
Hence, by [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) we get
\begin{align}
Pr[U(t)\ge 1] &\le E[U(t)] \\
&\le  m \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)^t
\end{align}
Note that for a collision to happen, we need to be left with at least one unsettled machine from the previous round. Therefore, $Pr[C(t)] \le Pr[U(t-1)\ge 1]$.
This yields:
\begin{align}
\sum_t Pr[C(t)] &\le \sum_t Pr[U(t-1)\ge 1]\\
&\le \sum_t m \cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{m^2}\right)^{t-1}\\
&\le  m^3
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use this in my research. May I know your name and affiliation to acknowledge please.

Comment: Sure, this is me: http://www.sfu.ca/~hodaa/

Comment: Could you please explain the last two inequalities of the first line $$\ge \frac{n-k}{n}\cdot \left(1-\frac{m-k-1}{n}\right)\ge 1-\frac{m-1}{n}\ge \frac{1}{m}.$$

Comment: is the final inequality $\geq \frac{1}{n}$? thanks

Comment: The last inequality holds because $1-\frac{m-1}{n}-\frac 1 m = \frac{m-1}{m}-\frac{m-1}{n} = (m-1)\cdot\left(\frac 1 m - \frac 1 n\right) \ge 0$. Probably the second last inequality is wrong and a factor $\frac 1 n$ should be added to the right hand side ($\frac{n-k}{n} \ge \frac {n-m} n \ge\frac 1 n$), so that the rightmost expression becomes $\frac 1{mn}$, and  the final answer becomes $nm^2$. Is that an acceptable answer for your paper? If not, there is still a chance to get better bounds with more careful analysis. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: I corrected the answer so that the final bound is still independent of $n$ (an additional factor of $\frac 1 m$ was missing). Hope this helps.

Comment: The second last was correct for $k<m<n$ which is our case. But certainly now it's better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $k$ machines do not have a fixed number yet. Then, there is some probability $0<p\leq 1$ that at least one machine will get a fixed number during the next round. The expected time needed for the first machine to find a fixed number is
$$\frac 1p=p+p(1-p)+p(1-p)^2+\dots$$
Because $p>0$, we know that $\frac 1p<\infty$. Thus, within a finite amount of time, there will be (at least) one machine less without a fixed number. For the new state, we can use the same argument. Because the number of machines $m$ is finite, we only need a finite amount of time $m$ times, which is finite. We know that $\frac 1p $ can't/won't go to infinity as the number of machines that is left decreases, because overall, there is only a finite amount of possible states the system can be in, and for every state we can calculate $p$ and then the the minimum of those values, which is a lower bound for all $p$'s .

The problem with this argument may be (I'm not sure) that it talks about the expected time for one machine to get a number, not about a worst case situation.

Comment: Very interesting view. So now the question is, how can we restate my problem so that this is the solution? Is this the answer to the question: If the machines follow the procedure in the original problem show that the expected time for the procedure to terminate is finite? Thank you.

Comment: @triomphe Yes, it is an answer to that exact question, but I don't exactly understand your original question about the sum of probabilities converging to zero.

Comment: @Ragnar What triomphe wants can follows from your argument using the "Markov inequality : $Pr[X> a E[X]] \le \frac{1}{a}$". If $E[X]$ is bounded by a constant, when $t = a E[X]$ goes to infinity, $\frac{1}{a} = E[X]/t$ tends to $0$.

Comment: @Hoda Could you please elaborate on your comment? thank you.

Comment: @Ragnar Suppose the event that at least one collision occurs at time $t$ is $C(t)$ with probability $P(C(t))$. Then I'm trying to say $\sum_tP(C(t))<\infty$. Does this make my question clear? Thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if you could edit the question and add the above comment. I thought you wanted to show that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} Pr(C(t)) = 0$. I will get back to you later.

Comment: @Hoda I edited the question. Thanks.